# Create Directory on Network Path

Tags: c#

I have a server application which receives packets of information (basically a file path on a network) from various client applications via WCF.  When it receives the incoming packet, it adds the file path to a list and then launches another process in a backgroundworker thread.  In my backgroundworker DoWork function, I call a function called ProcessFiles() - note I've simplified this function to make the sample easier.

```
private bool ProcessFiles()
{
  while (FileList.Count > 0)
  {
    var path = Path.Combine(FileList[0].TargetPath, @"\Translated Files");
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    FileList.RemoveAt(0);
  }
  return true;
}
```

The function above simply starts working through the FileList and right now the only action I'm trying to do is simply create a new directory inside the target path destination.  Now, this path is likely going to be on a network drive (I'm not sure if that matters)... but the server has access to that location.  When I run my server/client applications and send it a file to process... theoretically it should create the new "Translated Files" folder in the TargetPath destination location... however, nothing ever gets created.  The odd thing is that my DoWork function in my background worker completes its process correctly.  I know this because I have a print statement in my RunWorkerCompleted event handler and it appears to be processing normally.  Does anyone have any ideas why this directory folder is not being created correctly?

Comment: "Occurs when the background operation has completed, has been canceled, or has raised an exception." Did you check for an exception?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Yes.  In my RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs, I check for e.Cancelled and e.Error... and have different print statements for each of these cases... however, now that you said this... I put a print statement to catch the e.Result of the event and it does throw and exception.  It appears to be a null reference exception... but now I need to track down why.

Comment: Ok... making minor headway.  I had to change things in my server so I could run it locally and debug what's happening.  It appears that when I call the Path.Combine() function... it never really put the two strings together into a single string (the function merely returned a string "\\Translated Files"... but it left off the first part.  If I just concatenate the strings using a plus (+) symbol, the path appears correct (although with double back slashes) but I get the error saying it could not find part of the path.  This happens on the CreateDirectory function.  Any ideas?

Comment: It may have something to do with how my path is specified.  If I just use a simple If statement to check if the RemoteFileList[0].TargetPath exists... it returns false... but it definitely does exist (the client is sending the folder path via a folder browser).  In the debugger, the path uses double back slashes in the file path.  Is that correct?

Comment: I have a hunch (although can't confirm just yet) that the issue is because I'm running my server application in an elevated state (ie. admin) because of the http WCF restrictions.  When that happens, I apparently don't have access to the network drives (which is weird). Here's an article which helps explain: http://www.winability.com/how-to-make-elevated-programs-recognize-network-drives/.  I'm currently looking into whether or not this is the issue or not.